# Is everything from the table returned and the filtration is happening locally?

Tags: azure-mobile-services, offline-caching

i am connecting to my remote tables and retrieving a user via his email and password like this:

```
 var x = await _table.GetAsyncItems().Where(x => x.Email == email).Where(x => x.Password == password).ToListAsync();
```

But when I do this step, I have noticed that inside my terminal, I see every entry that is inside that table:

[image]

See the last line. There I see tester@tester.de, but I requested a whole different user. That user does exist and in the end is returned to me, but why can I see every content inside that table?

My fear now is that the above statement gets ALL items from the table and then filters them locally, which of course is not just a huge security risk but especially work intens.
Obviously I wanted the server to just return the items in question and not my local system.

Am I wrong here or did I misunderstand the way .Where() works?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Can I see the `GetAsyncItems()` definition?

Comment: This is from the entity framework sdk, all I can give you is this: IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAsyncItems ();

Comment: _"[`GetAsyncItems()` is] from the entity framework sdk"_ - no, it's something written by you or your coworkers.

Comment: I am sorry, but thats not the case. This is from the framework.

Comment: [No, it is not](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fef6%20GetAsyncItems&type=code) [from "the framework"](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fefcore%20GetAsyncItems&type=code), unless you mean your company's framework. Read [ask] and provide a [mre]. We don't know what `_table` is, nor what `GetAsyncItems()` is. I do know your problem is in either of those, so you'll need to show what they are.

Comment: And don't get me started on storing plaintext passwords. It's 2023 for crying out loud, not 2003.

Comment: First; yes it is. See this manual from microsoft where this is explained. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/xamarin-forms/?pivots=vs2022-windows

Comment: And secondly; this is a production envoirment. Password encryption just hasnt happend yet. THank you for your input, although no one has asked for it.

Comment: When multiple people replied to your question, you must @tag them to notify them. The page you link to does not contain `GetAsyncItems()`. But good for you that removing a method call solved the issue.

Comment: After this I'll stop bothering you, but _"my fear now is that the above statement gets ALL items from the table and then filters them locally, which of course is not just a huge security risk"_ - do you know what you are building? You're relying on your **client app** to construct an OData query to only return the current user. Anyone with access to your app can decompile it or inspect its network traffic, and **execute that query without the `.Where()`**. They will then see all your users, and their plaintext passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use Entity Framework, only used Entity Framework Core,

But I suspect the `GetAsyncItems()` is the one retrieving all rows from the database.

So by removing that piece of code to be like this :

```
var x = await _table.Where(x => x.Email == email).Where(x => x.Password == password).ToListAsync();
```

I believe the filtering will work on database site and the data will only be returned to client when this piece of code are called: `ToListAsync();`

Comment: Thank you man! You were absolutely right!

Answer (score 3):

The `GetAsyncItems()` method is from the [Azure Mobile Apps SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/offline?pivots=vs2022-windows), from a feature named [offline data sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/offline?pivots=vs2022-windows).

The method is meant to return, through an OData call to your Azure-hosted `TableController<Foo>`, "all instances from the table as an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`".

So what it does, is build an OData query (without the actual query part), retrieve all records as JSON, and lets you asynchronously enumerate the results:

```cs
DatasyncClient _cliend = new DatasyncClient(...)
IRemoteTable<User> _table = _client.GetRemoteTable<User>();

await foreach (var user in _table.GetAsyncItems())
{
}
```

This is for offline data synchronization purposes. You then query your offline database after synchronizing.

If you want to execute a specific query, build and pass that:

```cs
IRemoteTable<User> _table;

var query = _table.CreateQuery().Where(u => u.Email == email);

await foreach (var user in _table.GetAsyncItems(query))
{
}
```

If you don't want `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` for `await foreach ()`, you can just call the query on the remote table directly:

```cs
var users = await _table.Where(u => u.Email == email).ToListAsync();
```

Here, `Where()` will build the OData query and `ToListAsync()` will call the service, deserialize the JSON and materialize the results.